# Parsing odd JSON Request

Tags: java, json, parsing

I know how to parse normal JSON objects using the org.json library, but I am confused as how I would parse this one as it has no array/object names.

```
[
    {
        "value1": null,
        "value2": null,
        "value3": "example"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are used to parsing JSON like:

```
new JSONObject(jsonText);
```

But in you current case, the top level JSON item isn't an object, its an array. (Its pretty common to have an object as the top level, but it is not required.) Instead of parsing it by passing it to JSONObject, you should pass it to JSONArray.

```
new JSONArray(jsonText)
```